# Code Implementation for ISO adjustment and Brightness Formula

Tags: opencv, image-processing, camera, exif, camera-calibration

Hello All,
1. I have images taken making the setting ISO-Auto(Implies The ISO will be set based on the Lighting environment). 
 2.  We have Brightness Value in the Properties of the image File.
The Problem is, I need to use some fixed thresholds to extract an object in my algorithm. Obviously, For fixed thresholds to work, The environment should be uniform. So, Images taken at different ISO values cannot be best for my algorithm.
 I need to make the images(Taken at Different ISOs) to fit best for my Algorithm. 
 Example: we know ISO-200 will be twice brighter than ISO-100.
But To nullify the additional brightness created by ISO-200, What manipulation should I do to image before I apply my thresholds? (I have only images taken at Different ISOs. I cannot Ask to adjust aperture or Shutter speed parameters to nullify the change produced by ISO-200 compared to ISO-100.(I have to nullify the change purely using my code)
[Screenshot Of Image properties window, Brightness value highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjYX6.jpg)

 The Image Properties window shows brightness value. 
How This value is calculated by Camera Software? (Iam using SM-T810 Tab front camera for this task).
 I have googled for the solution. http://johnlind.tripod.com/science/scienceexposure.html
 This link gave a good explanation of brightness value(Bv). But the Formula application is not resulting the Brightness vlue shown in properties.
 is this link, the solution to brightness value calculation? 
 Please help me on finding the solution to this problem. 
[image: Other Properties of camera found in properties of image]
 Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve?

If you take an image with say ISO-100 and another image with say ISO-200, then from Wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APEX_system#Use_of_APEX_values_in_Exif

The brightness value is

`B(...) = log_2 ( A^2 / ( T S N ) )`,

where `A`, `T`, `S`, `N` are aperture value, shutter speed, ASA-speed and scaling constant respectively.

As a function of ASA-speed only

`B( S ) = constant - log_2( S )`,

so a scene captured with

`B( 200 ) = constant - log_2( 2 * 100 ) = B(100) - 1`

is one *stop* less bright. Put in other words, if brightness comes down one stop, then to compensate you must double the ASA speed or shutter speed (or open the aperture by 1.4).

Photoshop has this adjustment as "exposure" for you to play with.

But it only makes sense, if your scene lighting doesn't change. Otherwise you are just extracting hilights per se, and not objects.

Comment: @mailactual: Thanks For Answering my question..                       Example,ISO-200 looks bright compared to ISO-100. Is there any mathematical way that 200 is brighter than 100? If so, then, I can nullify the brightness in 200 using that mathematical relation. My Target is, the result image should be brought to one fixed ISO(Say to ISO-100) though image is taken at any ISOs

Comment: @Pavan, you don't need the brightness value as I said, you just tune the exposure by one stop (remember the photog lesson?). Just find out how exposure works in photoshop or camera manufacturers' software.

Comment: Iam making some search on how these parameters are being calculated. One doubt I have is, Is the Brightness value in the Screenshot attached(in properties window of image file) in above question, is the 'B' value in formula, you pointed to? Pls reply @mainactual

Comment: @Pavan, do you have shutter speed, aperture value and ISO readings available? Don't see them in the screenshot.

Comment: @mainactual- I have edited the question with screenshot of Other camera parameters recorded. For the image with these camera properties, brightness value is 2.34

Comment: @Pavan, B=log_2( 2.2^2/( 1/33 * 100 * 0.3 ) ) = 2.41 which is close enough. Last constant, see Wikipedia.

Comment: @mainactual- Thank You,... This is very close to solution of my problem.. The Brightness calculation is clear now. One doubt is, As, ISO-speed increases, brightness value increases.(If Iam correct). But here, the relation is inversely proportional right.. Is there any constant to be added/multiplied to this value?

Comment: @Pavan, if ISO-speed increases in the equation, then B actually decreases. Its inverse-logarithmic, thus its linear. In contrary, the perceived brightness of the scene increases when you increase the ISO (the scene burns white) because the sensor is tuned more sensitive. It's simple: you set the reference `B` (e.g. ISO-100, 1/60s @f/2.8) and either using the equation (`A` `S` `T`) or EXIF-value you calculate the difference in *stops*. If there is enough dynamics, you have a good change to compensate at least +/-2 stops using Photoshop-a like exposure adjustment.

Comment: @mainactual- Thanks Mate..:) This discussion helped me to gain knowledge of my task,. Thank You for the Help..